# Computer randomly shuts down with a fading alarm power button and CD drive

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, shutdown

I am currently experiencing something very very odd. Having build my PC myself, I have never had any issues (or anything heat related).

A few moments ago my computer shut down very randomly and everything goes blank, when I looked down on my case's power button it was fading on and off in such way I've had never seen before. I noticed the CD drive all of a sudden also started blinking randomly.

What do you guys think this problem is related to? It is definitely not a overheating issue and I am pretty sure my 600 watt power supply didn't blow because right now I am able to turn it on and boot up the PC but 20 seconds later it shuts down (sometimes doesn't shut down for 2 minutes). I have no idea what this is...

My specs are (built by myself):

- i5 3570k (unoverclocked)
- GTX 560ti
- Asrock Z77 Pro4-M motherboard
- 8GB Vengeance RAM
- 600W Corsair power supply
- 500GB of Seagate HD
- Case: Corsair Carbide 300R

Comment: you need to troubleshoot obviously. See if it happens in the BIOS.  remove unnecessary things(no need to have cd drive connected when testing this, though probably no harm, but may as well disconnect it, to get bare bones). Try changing the power supply.

Comment: What does your motherboard's manual say the LED fading in and out means?  Usually it just means it's in sleep state.  Really though, "My computer did this thing, what could it be?" is way too broad in my opinion. How do you 'know' it's not an overheating problem? What exactly have you tried already?

Comment: Also: In this state does the computer react to keyboard or the power button? Does this problem happen when the operating system is not running (e.g. you are in the BIOS setup)?

Comment: Guys thanks a lot for the help. I may have found the problem. The CPU stock fan has stopped working, so my guess is that CPU has been extremely overheating. Do u guys reckon that the CPU is alright and will work fine when I replace the fan?

Answer (score 0):

Yea that sounds like overheating. If you don't have a running fan on your CPU heatsink, It will probably be able to survive for a little while without overheating. If you have a CPU without a heatsink at all, the CPU will probably not survive longer than a second. To my knowledge, all modern hardware can account for this. It will shut off the system before any real harm is done. I would suggest not turning it on any more until you get a new fan. Also, if you are overclocking, I would not suggest using the stock fan and heatsink, as the extra heat may put to much work on them.